# Add User from Admin with Devise in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I m new to ROR, I want to add Sign-in and Sign-up in my ROR application to add users with role "Admin" and "Vendor" and for this i m using Devise, which created Sign-In and Sign-up and are working fine. Now i want to create a "Add user" section from where Admin can add user having role "vendor".

As i see Devise uses

```
"users/sign_in" and "/users/sign_up"
```

actions but there is no action to add a new user. Once Admin login we cannot use "/users/sign_up" , so i created a new controller "User" which using the same "Users" modal created by Devise. When trying to save new user action always got to "/users" and so calling the Devise default controller

I m not sure how i can add new users from Admin login and keep Devise in use as well for Authentication and Authorization,

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a user model, you'll need to add something like:

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

Then you crete the Admin::UsersController that creates a user model. The fact that the user will use devise to authenticate becomes immaterial.

Comment: After adding namespace , i m getting this error 'No route matches [GET] "/users"', any idea? and user modal has already been created using Devise, please help.....

Comment: With the namespace, the URL is admin/users